# How to make files single quotes using eslint in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint

I'd like to make files be single-quotes on save without prettier and using only eslint or configuring basic VScode settings.

I've read that the `.eslintrc.js` needs to be edited to change double-quotes to single-quotes on save, but where is it located in VScode? I've tried searching in settings but could not find `.eslintrc.js`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is working for me

My eslint.rc

```
{
     ... //other options
     "rules": {
        "quotes": [2, "single"]
      }
}
```

My vscode settings.json

```
{
   ...,
   "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
      "source.fixAll.eslint": true
    },
   "eslint.validate": [
      "typescript",
      "typescriptreact"
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in your vscode settings, add these:

```json
"javascript.preferences.quoteStyle": "single",
"typescript.preferences.quoteStyle": "single"
```